# GBZ80: How does LD HL,(SP+e) affect H and C flags?

Tags: assembly, z80, gameboy

On Gameboy Z80, exactly how does the `LD HL,(SP+e)` operation affect H and C flags? (Half-carry + carry)

Reference: http://www.devrs.com/gb/files/opcodes.html

Comment: They're probably set as per the result of `SP+e`, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Is it useful somehow? Or is it just an artifact of how it is implemented on the processor? I can't really see why anyone would be interested in that information.

Comment: I'd guess artifact. But it's just a guess.

Comment: Indeed, the docs you linked to conflicts with the pan-koopa docs: `HL <- (SP + s_offset8)` vs `HL <- SP + s_offset8`.

Comment: This other chart http://www.pastraiser.com/cpu/gameboy/gameboy_opcodes.html matches the Pan-Koopa docs.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I realise this is an old question but I had a similar problem a while ago and would just like to add my solution as there is absolutely no documentation or open-source emulator that does it correctly to my knowledge. Took me some actual debugging on a real gameboy to find the solution.

For both 16bit SP + s8 (signed immediate) operations:

the carry flag is set if there's an overflow from the 7th to 8th bit.

the half carry flag is set if there's an overflow from the 3rd into the 4th bit.

I found it easier to do the behaviour separately for both a positive and negative signed immediate (Lua):

```
local D8 = self:Read(self.PC+1)
local S8 = ((D8&127)-(D8&128))
local SP = self.SP + S8 

if S8 >= 0 then
    self.Cf = ( (self.SP & 0xFF) + ( S8 ) ) > 0xFF
    self.Hf = ( (self.SP & 0xF) + ( S8 & 0xF ) ) > 0xF
else
    self.Cf = (SP & 0xFF) <= (self.SP & 0xFF)
    self.Hf = (SP & 0xF) <= (self.SP & 0xF)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As seen here: http://www.pastraiser.com/cpu/gameboy/gameboy_opcodes.html The sum of SP+e affects the Half Carry and the Carry flag, so you should check if there's carry from bit 3 to 4 and from 7 to 8 (Starting by 0!)